# JavaScript runtime error: "$" is undefined - ASP.NET WebForms (MasterPage)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms, master-pages

I hope someone can help me because i'm not able to find a working solution for my problem.

I'm coding in ASP.NET WebForms with C#. I use a MasterPage.
In this MasterPage i define my scripts in a ScriptManager.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="smScripts" runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/printArea.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/globalFunctions.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery.browser.min.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery.reject.js" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Now, if i use jQuery in any page e. g. Default.aspx inside a function it works fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Print(options) {
        $("div.PrintArea").printArea(options);
    }
</script>
```

But if i try to use it directly in the script block - for example to wait until the document is ready - it doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // some code
    });
</script>
```

I get the error "JavaScript runtime error: "$" is undefined".
I don't know how i can fix this issue.

Maybe someone can help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably, your `<script>` tags are located **before** jQuery reference. By the time you call a function, jQuery is already loaded and works properly. But when you try to do `$(document).ready` it is not loaded and throws this error. I am 95% percent sure. Open the generated HTML and see if it is. jQuery should be referenced before `$(document).ready` or any other usage.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You could be right, but how can i ensure that jQuery is always loaded **before** any other code is called (in my MasterPage)?

Comment: Sometimes, this happened to me, too. Always it was because of using 3rd party JSs, that scythes among themselves. Try to comment all the JSs and then uncomment them little by little.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure

```
 <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" />
```

is written/loaded before you call

```
$(document).ready(function ()
```

your code "function Print(options)" is working fine because jquery library was not loaded when page was ready but loaded after some time. Your Print function need jquery when called and not on page ready event.

Answer (score 0):

Let say we want to add jquery in every page, so you need to include a reference of your script in your masterpage.

According to the best practices, you should put all javascript references and scripts at the end of the `<body>` html tag: just before the `</body>` tag.

So in your case, you should reference all your common js file at the end of the `<body>` tag and then set a section like that :

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="myJsWhatever" runat="server">

</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

So in pages that inherit from the master page you defined all your JS in this section and you ensure jquery is loading first.

If you don't want to change all your stuff, just add the jquery reference in the `head` section of your html page.

Comment: The problem is, that the ScriptManager is in the body section of the masterpage. The ContentPalceHolder for my head is in the head section. So i think in a content page the head is loaded before the ScriptManager in the body of the masterpage is loaded.

Comment: @CSharper, you need to add a direct js reference like that `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>` not use the ScriptManager  for this kind of references

Comment: Now i do so. And this works. But with "~/Scripts/..." the content pages are not able to load the script. So i load the script directly from my server like this: src="https://...". Maybe there is a better way? Have a look to my answer, too.

Answer (score 0):

If i use simple script tags **before** the ContentPlaceHolder instead of the ScriptManager it works:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://.../jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="phHead" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

To ensure the path is correct on every content page i load it directly from my server instead of using a path like "~/scripts/...". Maybe there is a better way?

Comment: Add the script like that : `<script runat="server" type="text/javascript" 
  src='<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js") %>'></script>`

Comment: If i use the script tag with the runat property it doesn't compile. If i use it without the runat property it complies but i get the following error: German original: Die Steuerelementeauflistung kann nicht geändert werden, da das Steuerelement Codeblöcke enthält (z.B. <% ... %>). English by Google: The controls list can not be modified because the control contains code blocks (ie <% ...%>).

Comment: @Thomas, maybe you can assist me one more time?

Comment: @Thomas: Unfortunately i'm not able to load my scripts with a file system path. I have to load them from a web path like "https://.../Scripts/jQuery.js" to get it work. How can i change this?

Comment: sorry can you update your question or add a new one ? it could be usefull for someone else and I need more information about the problem you encounter, exception, etc ... thanks in advance.